# Update git subdirectory after filter-branch

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'm new to git, I'm interested in keeping update a directory in a git repository, I'm cloning the repository and running filter-branch on it:

```
git clone http://url.git
cd repository
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter directory-I-m-interested
```

This is awesome, the repository now have the contents of the directory-I-m-interested in the root path, however I'm still not sure how to keep the files on this directory in sync with the original project.

I've tried with the following commands:

```
git fetch
git cherry-pick hash_taken_from_last_command
```

and I get the following error:

```
error: could not apply a0ede43... 2
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

Probably I'm just executing non sense, any hints?

Comment: What's the reason that you need to throw away the other directories?

Comment: I'm creating a project which will use plugins, each of these plugins should have the same root path.., e,g. ~/.program/{plugin1,plugin2..,}, some of these plugins have very shy content (10 or so lines of code) so I think having a repository for each of them is overkill, I've created a program-plugin repository containing several of them. Now I clone the general plugin repository with the name of each plugin and clean every but the current plugin. It's working now, the update mechanism is what is missing.

Comment: So rather that cloning into `$CONFIG_PATH/plugins` you clone into `$CONFIG_PATH/plugins` subdirectories several times to manually reasemble a `$CONFIG_PATH/plugins` directory containing subdirectories for the plugins?

Comment: Either use one big repository for all the plugins, and be glad that it's easy to use, and you have them all nicely organized within a single coherent structure, or have a number of small repositories, one for each plugin, and also be glad that it's easy to use, and you can clone whichever plugins you need whenever you want, without worrying about a few kB Git overhead for the tiniest repos. What you have now is overcomplicated for no clear benefit.

Comment: Since the $CONFIG_PATH/plugins is intend to contain not just my plugins but plugins made by others, the second approach (even if it means to have a lot of extra repositories) seems the only reasonable way. I just wanted to poke and see if there was some git magic who could do it. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a sparse checkout. Look here

http://briancoyner.github.io/blog/2013/06/05/git-sparse-checkout/

for instance. It restricts the working copy (checked out files) in git to a subset of the original git repository. You can follow the original as normal with git but just see the part of it you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing non sense.  I believe you are looking for functionality of `svn` as you are only wanting to use one sub-directory.  With the local repository after the above `git filter-branch` command, a `git push` probably would fail and a `git push -f` would wipe away the other directories of the repository.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to answer, I'm not looking for pushing anything back, I'd just to keep in sync with an specific directory, I suppose I could just delete the whole repository and filter-branch on each 'update'

Answer (score 0):

Git offers pretty strong guarantees about the integrity of the repository. Running `git filter-branch` is a deep surgical operation that results in a completely new repository with all the commit checksums recalculated etc. You have in fact rewritten the whole history of the project, so during fetching and merging changes from the old repository Git will correctly complain that it doesn't recognize the new, changed history of the repository. There's no way for Git to have split personality and at the same time remember and forget about the rest of the directories.

As you say, you're new to Git, so please reconsider if you really need to do such deep and intrusive surgical operations on your repository.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, yep, probably there is no need for filter-branching the whole repository, deleting and recreating the repository on each 'update' could do it, as could an sparse checkout + softlinks, if I'm not lost.